# Calling seek of ConsumConsumerSeekCallback from a Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-kafka

Here is my setup:

ConsumerSeekAware implementation:

```
public class ReplayJobKafkaConsumer implements ConsumerSeekAware, AcknowledgingMessageListener<String, String> {

    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> map, ConsumerSeekCallback consumerSeekCallback) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onIdleContainer(Map<TopicPartition, Long> map, ConsumerSeekCallback consumerSeekCallback) {

    }

    private static final ThreadLocal<ConsumerSeekCallback> seekCallBack = new ThreadLocal<>();

    private static ConsumerSeekCallback consumerSeekCallback;;

    @Override
    public void registerSeekCallback(ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
        this.seekCallBack.set(callback);
        consumerSeekCallback = callback;
    }

    public void onMessage(final ConsumerRecord<String, String> data, final Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
    }

    public static ThreadLocal<ConsumerSeekCallback> getSeekCallback(){
        return seekCallBack;
    }

    public static ConsumerSeekCallback getAnotherSeekCallback(){
        return consumerSeekCallback;
    }
}
```

My Spring Boot application approximates to:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ReplayJobApplication{
...
public void run(final String... args){
        context = SpringApplication.run(ReplayJobApplication.class, args);
        ReplayJobKafkaConsumer.getAnotherSeekCallback().seek("top", 0, 23);
    }
...}
```

The above setup works. Now I can run this application using

```
java -jar -Dstart.offset=0....
```

But it only works if the seekcallback variable is not a ThreadLocal. I need this to be accessible at the Spring Boot application as that is how I intend running this consumer. TEMP-TOPIC's other consumers can still be processing, but I intend to run this consumer on a need basis with a start and end offset. While the command line parameters can be read in the consumer, the concerns I have are

1. callback variable is static (I cannot possibly create an instance of ReplayJobKafkaConsumer
2. it is a plain variable and not a ThreadLocal

Though the life time of this container is only going to be from start to end, I wonder if this setup is flawed and need some confirmation that this implementation is OK.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have some fundamental misunderstanding of what's going on.

1. The `ThreadLocal` is needed because the Kafka consumer object is not thread-safe. If you store the callback in a ThreadLocal, you can perform arbitrary seek operations at runtime - either from the `onMessage` method, or by listening for an `ListenerContainerIdleEvent` when there are no messages.
2. You can't perform arbitrary seeks `ReplayJobKafkaConsumer.getAnotherSeekCallback().seek("top", 0, 23);` from another thread.
3. You can't perform arbitrary seeks before partitions have been assigned.

So, as I have been telling you in other answers/comments, you must do the seek when the partition(s) are assigned.

```
@Override
public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> map, ConsumerSeekCallback consumerSeekCallback) {
    // Do the seeks here using the `consumerSeekCallback` parameter.
}
```

With modern versions of spring-kafka, you don't need to use `ConsumerSeekAware` unless you want to perform arbitrary seeks at runtime (after the initial seek). You can use a `ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener` instead.

Comment: Indeed sir. I misunderstood arbitrary to include "anytime" and "anywhere", mistaken on the latter. onPartitionsAssigned is an elegant solution for me as I do not need to manually issue a seek. However just one question - assuming this is an independent container, with its own consumer - threading is not really an issue, is it? So using the callback outside this thread seems safe in so as long as this is run as a separate entity. Isnt that the reason why you allow the callback's seek to trigger from my boot application leaving threading risks to me? Its more of a recommendation than a rule, no?

Comment: It is to protect your application; if you perform a seek while the listener container is calling `poll()` you will likely encounter issues. Read the `KafkaConsumer` javadocs; the only "safe" method that can be called on a different thread is `wakeup()` to wake the consumer from `poll()`.

Comment: I used onPartitionsAssigned method to seek and it works fine. Now I need to "stop" when the offset reaches a value. I thought KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.stop would help, so I autowired that in my consumerseekaware listener but calling stop does not stop the consumer. Out of curiosity I dumped the size of both getListenerContainerIds and getListenerContainers - both were 0. I need to stop the consumer as soon as the end offset is reached. I know SprinApplication.exit is an option but that is not elegant. Also I dont know how to get a handle to listener container from within the consumer.

Comment: The endpoint registry is only for `@KafkaListener` POJO method listeners. If you declare the listener container as a `@Bean` you can simply auto-wire it. You should not stop() the container on the listener thread; hand off the stop() to a different thread. There may be more (prefetched) records after the one you want to stop at so your listener needs to discard them.

Comment: Hmmm, prefetch is definitely going to be an issue as I SHOULD not process any more after end offset is reached. A SpringApplication.exit seems like a sure shot method. Is there any downside to killing the entire spring boot app in terms of leaks etc.?

Comment: No, `system.exit()` should be fine.

Comment: My kafka config has 

`@Bean
public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> listenerContainer() {...
 }`

Yet when I autowire it in my consumer seek aware class above as 

`@Autowired
    private ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer;
`

I end up with a 

`Failed to start bean 'listenerContainer'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaDataListener implementation must be provided`

Dont know why this is so?

Comment: Don't put code in comments; it's too hard to read; edit the question instead. A listener container needs a listener bean in the container properties; the listener is invoked with records retrieved from Kafka. You need to pass a reference to your `ReplayJobKafkaConsumer` there.